# How to correctly access in a type-safe way the ref.current of a forwardRef element in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref, react-forwardref

Here's a minimal example o the type-safety problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-dream-8v7kgu?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const CanvasContainer = forwardRef<HTMLCanvasElement>((props, parentRef) => {
  const localRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = parentRef ?? localRef;

  useEffect(() => {
    // type-safety no longer works here, see code sandbox link
    console.log(canvasRef.current);
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
});
```

With typescript, the `canvasRef` can be more than just a `React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>`. Why, and how can we achieve type-safety and access the `.curent` value in this situation?

Note:

- The `localRef` and `parentRef` pattern was taken from [Optional forwardRef that is required inside - ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676799/optional-forwardref-that-is-required-inside-reactjs) and appears to be a decent way of normalising optional refs sent this way.
- This is an isolated case where I want to figure out how to support this kind of code pattern. There are other ways to achieve the functionality that I am implementing without forwardRef. I'm not asking for a solution related to my canvas feature, but for a clarification of how react and the types of react can be tamed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, TS is saving you from a possible mistake. If you check out the signature of `forwardRef`, the `parentRef` is a union type: `((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null`. I.e. it may be a reference (in which case it has a `.current` property), or a *setter function* or *null* (in which case it does not have the `.current` property).

Comment: yeah, after playing around with it I ended up with a check if parentRef is not typeof 'function'. I'll post the code in a few days unless some comes up with a battle-tested solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this solution, since I am sure I only want to support normal refs or no refs at all and like the first comment of the question states (from Nikos), the ref could also be a setter function.

```
const CanvasContainer = forwardRef<HTMLCanvasElement>((props, parentRef) => {
    if (typeof parentRef === "function") {
        throw new Error(
            `Only React Refs that are created with createRef or useRef are supported`
        )
    }

    const localRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)
    const canvasRef = parentRef ?? localRef
// ...
```